# How to overload << and >> to use them for file writing and reading of a class

Tags: c++, file-io, operator-overloading

I have tried to overload << and >> operators for a class so that it can write into a file or read from it directly in the following way.

```
class Record
{
public:
    int key;
    string fname;
    string lname;
    string addr;
    Record(){}
    Record(int k,string f, string l, string a):key(k),fname(f),lname(l),addr(a){}
    Record operator=(Record r2)
    {
        key=r2.key;
        fname=r2.fname;
        lname=r2.lname;
        addr=r2.addr;
    }
    friend bool operator==(const Record r1,const Record r2)
    {
        if((r1.key==r2.key)&&(r1.fname==r2.fname)&&(r1.lname==r2.lname)&&(r1.addr==r2.addr))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    friend ostream operator<<(ostream os,Record r)
    {
        os<<r.key<<" "<<r.fname<<" "<<r.lname<<" "<<r.addr<<"\n";
        return os;
    }
    friend istream operator>>(istream is,Record r)
    {
        is>>r.key>>r.fname>>r.lname>>r.addr;
        return is;  
    }
};
int main()
{
    Record r(3,"Tarun","Maganti","Hyd"),buff;    
    cout<<r;
    ifstream file1("file.txt");
    file1>>buff;
    cout<<endl<<buff;
}
```

When I did that, there seems to be a lot of errors. I want to be able to use the same operator to write/read from a console or a file like it is in the main function of the above program.

---

Here is the error output:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39:0,
                 from CDCv2.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/5/ostream: In function ‘std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream, Record)’: /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:393:7: error: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
_Traits>::basic_ostream(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ is protected
       basic_ostream(basic_ostream&& __rhs)
       ^ CDCv2.cpp:68:10: error: within this context    return os;
          ^ In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:40:0,
                 from CDCv2.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/5/istream: In function ‘std::istream operator>>(std::istream, Record)’: /usr/include/c++/5/istream:613:7: error: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT,
_Traits>::basic_istream(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ is protected
       basic_istream(basic_istream&& __rhs)
       ^ CDCv2.cpp:73:10: error: within this context    return is; 
          ^ In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:40:0,
                 from CDCv2.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/5/istream: In function ‘int main()’: /usr/include/c++/5/istream:611:7: error: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_istream(const std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ is protected
       basic_istream(const basic_istream&) = delete;
       ^ CDCv2.cpp:83:7: error: within this context    ol>>buff;
       ^ CDCv2.cpp:83:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_istream(const std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:40:0,
                 from CDCv2.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/5/istream:611:7: note: declared here
       basic_istream(const basic_istream&) = delete;
       ^ CDCv2.cpp:70:17: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::istream operator>>(std::istream, Record)’   friend istream operator>>(istream is,Record r)
                 ^ In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:40:0,
                 from CDCv2.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/5/istream:611:7: error: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_istream(const std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ is protected
       basic_istream(const basic_istream&) = delete;
       ^ CDCv2.cpp:89:7: error: within this context    ne>>buff;
       ^ CDCv2.cpp:89:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_istream(const std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:40:0,
                 from CDCv2.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/5/istream:611:7: note: declared here
       basic_istream(const basic_istream&) = delete;
       ^ CDCv2.cpp:70:17: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::istream operator>>(std::istream, Record)’   friend istream operator>>(istream is,Record r)
                 ^ CDCv2.cpp:92:2: error: a template declaration cannot appear at block scope   template <class T>   ^ CDCv2.cpp:112:11: error: ‘intersection’ was not declared in this scope for_each(intersection.begin(),intersection.end(),[](Record r){cout<<r;})
           ^ In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39:0,
                 from CDCv2.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/5/ostream: In lambda function: /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:391:7: error: ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ is protected
       basic_ostream(const basic_ostream&) = delete;
       ^ CDCv2.cpp:112:70: error: within this context   for_each(intersection.begin(),intersection.end(),[](Record r){cout<<r;})
                                                                      ^ CDCv2.cpp:112:70: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39:0,
                 from CDCv2.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:391:7: note: declared here
       basic_ostream(const basic_ostream&) = delete;
       ^ CDCv2.cpp:65:17: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream, Record)’   friend ostream operator<<(ostream os,Record r)
```

Comment: you should not copy the streams but pass and return references

Comment: Thanks. It worked.

Comment: @TarunMaganti Was the solution effective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operators `operator<<` and `operator>>` are overloaded using a return-by-reference because they take in objects and output the `cout` (or `cin`) object containing those objects. Try:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Record& g) {
    //do stuff here
}
```

They need to be returned-by-reference because they have to be able to take in other stream objects that derive from it, such as `ifstream`. Now your program can read files that contain `Record` objects.

The main reason for the error is because the constructor for `basic_ostream` (which `iostream` is a child of, which `cin` is a type of) is protected (which is also what your error says). But did you see that because it's protected, its children (`cin`, `cout`) can be instantiated?

Unfortunately `iostream` doesn't have a `operator>>` or `operator<<` function, so we can't declare `iostream& operator>>(iostream& iO, myType mT)`. So we have to use `ostream` types.

Comment: the compiler error is caused by OP attempting to copy the streams. You fix that in your snippet but your explanation is wrong

Comment: moreover OPs `operator<<` and `operator>>` are indeed free functions (see here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend)

Comment: @tobi303 Thanks for responding. I've fixed the explanation. Is it correct, now?

Comment: @TarunMaganti was this solution effective?

Comment: The answer was helpful but I didn't understand why if they are "streams" that they should be passed and returned through reference. I can visualize why it might work and it worked for me but I would prefer an explanation of what happens to streams when you pass by value and return by value and when you pass-by-reference and return-by-reference

Comment: @TarunMaganti Hi, I've edited my answer. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes. This is much understandable. It helps.